# XElement and XName crashes when xml has namespace to root node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

Hi i was fiddeling around with xml files and i notised something i have a bit problem of solving.

I have a Xml that starts with a root node and then has another child node that can change name for example:

```
<root>
  <Child1>
</root>
```

So given that "Child1" can be changed to "Child2" or "Child3" i made this linq  be able to extract the name from whatever comes my way.

first:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

var childType = root.Descendants().First(x => x.Name == "Child1" || x.Name == "Child2"|| x.Name == "Child3").Name;
```

So when i have my xml without a namespace, as shown above, it workes fine, i manage to extract the name from the node tag.

But when i have a namespace into the root tag it throws an error:

```
<root xmlns="namespace">
  <Child1>
</root>
```

That xml going through the same linq, throws:

> Sequence contains no matching element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `root` element has a namespace defined (`xmlns="namespace"`) thus all child elements are associated with the same namespace. I.e. `Child1` element will be in the same namespace, and its name will contain both namespace prefix and local name (`"Child1"`). So you can either specify full name when searching for `Child1` element:

```
var ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var childType = root.Descendants()
   .First(x => x.Name == ns +"Child1" || x.Name == ns + "Child2"|| x.Name == ns + "Child3")
   .Name;
```

Or you can look for `x.Name.LocalName` (but I don't recommned this approach, though it's unlikely you will have `Child1` elements from another namespace).

Note: your `Child` element does not have closing tag (probably it's a misprint)

Further reading: [Xml Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Comment: It's probably worth explaining that this is due to namespace defaulting with `xmlns=...`. I was going to do that, but figured it would be *mostly* a duplicate of your answer...

Comment: This worked perfectly and was exactly the answer i was looking for, thank you.